# Show that a function of two variables is continuous at origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Define
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 {|x|}^\beta y}{x^4 + y^2},  & \text{if $x \neq$ 0} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x = 0$},
\end{cases}$$
where $\beta>0$.
By using epsilon delta definition, I want to show that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at origin.
My attempt is following " I am finding $\delta > 0$ such that $|(x,y) - (0,0)| < \delta$ (i.e. $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta $)  implies

$$|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| < \epsilon \implies \left|\frac{x^2 {|x|}^\beta y}{x^4 + y^2} \right| < \epsilon.$$

I got stuck here how to proceed further. Please help . Give me any suggestion how to proceed further ? Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: $\beta > 0 , \beta \in \Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the AM-GM inequality, $|x^2y|\le (x^4+y^2)/2.$

Comment: $\left|\frac{x^2 {|x|}^\beta y}{x^4 + y^2} \right| \le \frac{|x|^\beta}{2} $ . Now how can i estimate $ |x|^ \beta$ for any $\beta > 0 $ so that i can find $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$

Comment: Let $\delta = \epsilon^{1/\beta}$ and use $\sqrt {x^2+y^2} <\delta\implies |x|<\delta.$

Comment: What led someone to downvote this? Please explain.

Comment: sir , I have not downvoted your question. and suddenly someone downvoted all my questions just after your (above) comment.This is not good as a humanity and as a good mathematician. WE are part of maths family.

Comment: @Smarty I know you didn't downvote it because you accepted my answer.